# Elasticsearch dynamic template to match several exact fields

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm currently struggling to simplify my mapping template files for Elasticsearch. Indeed, I got several `Object` fields that have the same structure (e.g. source and destination here)

Is there a way to set up Dynamic template so that it can match several patterns ?

Here's what I execute:

```
POST /_template/mapping-lol
{
  "template": "*-newevents-*",
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "system": {
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "match": "^(source|destination)$",
            "mapping": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "first": {
                      "type": "text"
                    },
                    "last": {
                      "type": "text"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "ip": {
                  "type": "ip"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "source": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": true
        },
        "destination": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /tenant-newevents-1/log
{
  "source": {
    "name": {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Doe"
    },
    "ip": "1.2.3.4"
  },
  "destination": {
    "name": {
      "first": "Jane",
      "last": "Doe"
    },
    "ip": "3.4.5.6"
  }
}

GET /tenant-newevents-1
```

This above does not work...

I've got plenty of these same schemes to match (~20).

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Looks good to me. Just tried on ES 5 and 6 and it worked out well. Please show how you create your index/mapping?

Comment: curl -XPOST "locallhost:9200/_template/mapping-events" -d@mymapping.json

Comment: good one !! What about the content of mymapping.json?

Comment: @Val I changed the format, it's better like this, more Kibana-able :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out what went wrong: Fields mustn't be mapped *at all* for Dynamic mapping to proceed. Removing "source" and "destination" schemes in mapping worked.

```
POST /_template/mapping-lol
{
  "template": "*-newevents-*",
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "system": {
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "match": "^(source|destination)$",
            "mapping": {
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "first": {
                      "type": "text"
                    },
                    "last": {
                      "type": "text"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "ip": {
                  "type": "ip"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That was my next comment ;-) Doesn't make sense to map them if you have dynamic templates for them.